# Generic method overloading and precedence in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
internal fun <T> T.printMe(): Unit {   // generic function for all types
    println(this)
}

internal fun CustomType.printMe(): Unit { // function for only customType class
    println("**** ${this} ******")
}

internal fun <T> printCustom(content: T) {
    content.printMe()
}

data class CustomType(val print: String)

fun main() {
    "Hello".printMe()
    CustomType("Testing").printMe()
    printCustom(CustomType("Testing"))
}
```

**Result**

```
Hello
**** CustomType(print=Testing) ******
CustomType(print=Testing)
```

I wonder why calling `printMe()` via another generic function `printCustom()` will prefer `T.printMe()` instead of `CustomType.printMe()`

Comment: Because overload selection is at compile-time, not runtime. The `printCustom` function _has no ide_ that `content` is a `CustomType` so the compiler will never resolve it to `CustomType.printMe`. (I don't know if Kotlin would wrire it up as you expect if you add a constraint on `T` or not, though...)

Comment: @Dai does `reified` will do the job here?

Comment: I doubt it (I'm not a Kotlin expert): C#'s generics are reified too and C# has the same problem (well, I don't see it as a problem, personally). Reified generics are most useful for value-types and using reflection with type-parameters - not overload selection.

Comment: Reified won't change the behavior. Function selection is done at compile time, which removes all ambiguity. You never have to worry that something might behave differently and violate the Liskov substitution principle. If you specifically want to create this behavior, then you can use reified type in a function so you can test the type using `if (T::class is CustomType::class)` and delegate to the other function as necessary.

Comment: @Tenfour04 can you give a link to the document or example? I'm getting error when try this

Comment: Hmm looks like I need to do like this `T::class.java.equals(CustomType::class.java)` or `T::class.equals(CustomType::class)`

Comment: @Tenfour04 is there any way to do this for List<T> ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `if (T::class == CustomType::class)`. Not sure exactly what you mean with the List.

Comment: I mean how do I do this check for List<CustomType> ? This seems working `if(T::Class.isInstance(listOf<CustomType>()))` is it right?